# Suse Enterprise 11 SP2 how to install git

Tags: linux, git, suse

I've never had a problem installing git on any Linux distro, but now I'm forced to use a client's server which is SLES 11 SP2. It uses `yast` or `zypper` to do package management, which I've never used before. Apparently I should be able to `zypper install git-core` but that doesn't work because it needs a certain repo added. Of course none of this is on the official git installation page [here](http://git-scm.com/download/linux).

I found what packages belong to the SLE11-SP2-SDK repo [here](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7003254). But no instructions on how to add the repo to yast or zypper.

I'll also accept an answer that simply tells me how to install git on a SLES server. I've already tried from source, but of course it's missing requirements which also belong to the SDK repo.

This is what I get when I do "zypper install git-core":

```
$ sudo zypper install git-core

Refreshing service 'nu_novell_com'.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'git-core' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'git-core' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but shouldn't `yast` or `zypper` handle the dependencies for you?

Comment: You would hope, but no. This is what I get when I do "zypper install git-core" (see edit above)

Comment: I just installed SuSE 12.3 and Git was installed by default.

Answer (score 54):

I figured it out, only by piecing together other info mainly from the OpenSUSE project.
Basically it's:

```
$ sudo zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/tools:/scm/SLE_11_SP2/devel:tools:scm.repo
$ sudo zypper install git-core
```

Comment: Pleased you sorted it out `:)`

Comment: This helped me out, started in the right direction. I had to add the perl repo also, b/c git depends on perl-Error.
# add devel perl repo
$ sudo zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/perl/SLE_11/devel:languages:perl.repo

Comment: For the perl one the above link didn't work for me. I used: sudo zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/perl/SLE_11_SP3/devel:languages:perl.repo

Comment: @Brade it would be nice if you update your answer with link from rooby - yours does not exist

Answer (score 6):

git is part of the SDK for SLES, which can be downloaded here:

http://download.novell.com (ideally for the currently used SP2)

Once you installed itm the zypper or yast commands work. It's not recommended to use openSUSE rpms within a SLES environment.

Answer (score 1):

#### Offline Install git on SLES 12 SP2  using SDK ISO

If you do not have direct access to the remote/online SLES zypper repositories, you can add ***SDK*** ISO as a repository. Some packages are available in this ISO.

1) Download **SLE-12-SP2-SDK-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso** from https://download.suse.com/Download?buildid=g3e7P21X6Lw~ (It requires sign-up). You can also find your desired ISO SDK at https://download.suse.com

2) Copy & transfer downloaded the file to the SLES machine. (here we transfer it to /temp/SLE-12-SP2-SDK-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso)

3) Add ISO as Zypper repository

```
zypper ar iso:/?iso=/temp/SLE-12-SP2-SDK-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso sdk_dvd
```

4) install git

```
zypper install git-core
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the SLES 11 SP2 **SDK** DVD's from [download.suse.com](http://download.suse.com). In order to access the downloads, you need to register a user account (it's free).

1. Once downloaded, mount the first DVD. (make sure it is for the correct architecture)
2. Load up YaST and go to Software->Add-on products.
3. Then select 'Add' and continue the installation by selecting the installation source, accepting the license, etc.
4. Repeat for DVD2, unless DVD1 had everything you needed.

Comment: How would I do this on a server? Even if it has an optical drive, I cannot easily access the physical server.

Comment: Use the add-on option in yast with the iso, no need to deal with physical media

Answer (score 0):

In `zypper` need to add the repository of `git` using `zypper addrepo <repo_url>` command, before trying to install it. You can get the repo URL of `git` package [here](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel%3Atools%3Ascm&package=git).

Answer (score -2):

I meet a silly problem during zypper refresh, later figured out that /tmp directory should be created ahead. After that, everything work out.

```
13392046a881:/ # zypper -v refresh
Verbosity: 1
Initializing Target
Specified repositories: 
Checking whether to refresh metadata for Software configuration management (SLE_11_SP3)
Retrieving: repomd.xml [done]
Repository 'Software configuration management (SLE_11_SP3)' is up to date.
Building repository 'Software configuration management (SLE_11_SP3)' cache [done]
Error building the cache:
[|] Failed to cache repo (3).
History:
- 'repo2solv.sh' '-o' '/var/cache/zypp/solv/devel_tools_scm/solv' '/var/cache/zypp/raw/devel_tools_scm'
mktemp: failed to create file via template `/tmp/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX': No such file or directory
```